# Обновление модели в базе данных Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Изменяю данные пользователя на сайте, user_'у присваиваются поля user'a, но изменения не вступают в силу. Если же изменять поля пользователя по отдельности (к примеру `user_.nickname = user.nickname` и т.д), то всё работает. В чем проблема?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(User user)
    {
        User user_ = await userContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == user.Id);
        user_ = user;            
        await userContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("UserList");
    }
```

Comment: Видимо, все дело в поле `Id`. В качестве параметра в метод приходит `user` с нулевым `Id`. Надо во View  создать скрытое поле, в котором сохранять `Id` редактируемого юзера.

Comment: @Bulson нет, всё уже есть
<input asp-for="User.Id" value="@Model.User.Id" type="hidden" />

Comment: Загружать юзера из бд не нужно. Просто надо установить правильный id и *прикрепить* юзера к контексту

Comment: Эм, стоп. Вы просто переписали ссылку в переменной и ожидаете, что совершенно другой объект поменяет чудесным образом свои свойства? Это так не работает.

Comment: `user_'у присваиваются поля user'a` - нет, не присваиваются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityFramework отслеживает состояние всех своих объектов во внутренних списках и реагирует на них. То есть у него внутри есть список ссылок на все объекты и что вы там делаете с внешней переменной ему все равно. Сейчас вы просто теряете ссылку на полученный объект и ничего не происходит.

Для того, чтобы EntityFramework нормально отреагировал, надо ему сказать явно переписать состояние внутреннего объекта на внешний. Делается это методом Attach:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(User user)
{
    userContext.Users.Attach(user);
    userContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);
    await userContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("UserList");
}
```